# Is Disk Drill able to recover extended attributes?

Tags: extended-attributes

Is Disk Drill, which is commercial file recovery software, able to recover extended attributes of normal files?

Comment: The importance of regular, comprehensive backups cannot be overstated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't.

For example, `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms`, which is automatically added to downloaded files in `~/Downloads`, is lost.

Extended attributes are also used in Photos library, but if you recover a library, the extended attributes that were added by Photos.app to RAW and JPEG files are lost.